# Why my componentWillRecieveProps not call when props changes Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here, my componentWillReceiveProps not call. Actually what I am doing.I have 2 component but I want to show my component conditionally. 
 Let's talk step by step ::=> 
 1. Here i am using switch to call my component.

```js
case 4 :
 return(
  <Hotspotmergepreview 
   xml = {this.state.xml} 
   remedStatus = {this.state.remediationToggle} 
   showAns = {this.showAns}
         />
 );
```

2. Above i call hotspotmergepreview component and i pass some data(xml) using props.

this is my component where i call my both component based on conditionally.

```js
  import React from 'react';

import HotspotPreview from '../components/HotspotPreview';
import Hotspotnewpreview from '../components/Hotspotnewpreview';

export default class Hotspotmergepreview extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        self = this
        this.cType = ''
        this.state = {
            xml:''
        }
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) { 
     if(this.props.xml != nextProps.xml) {
            const newXml = XMLToJSON(nextProps.xml)
            this.cType = newXml.smxml.div._type
            this.setState({
                xml:nextProps.xml
            })
        }
    }
    render(){
        if(this.cType == 'w' || this.cType == 's' || this.cType == 'p') {
            console.log("inside"+this.cType)
            return(
                <Hotspotnewpreview
                    xml = {this.state.xml} 
                    remedStatus = {this.props.remediationToggle} 
                    showAns = {this.props.showAns}
                />
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <HotspotPreview 
                    xml = {this.state.xml} 
                    remedStatus = {this.props.remediationToggle} 
                    showAns = {this.props.showAns}
                /> 
            );
        }
    }    
}
```

3. my main component where i recieve all data using componentwillreceiveprops. but this lifecycle not works properly.

```js
 export default  class Hotspotnewpreview extends React.Component {
     constructor(props){
        super(props);
        self = this

        this.state ={
            templateType: 'default',
        }

        this.templateArea = this.templateArea.bind(this)
        this.checkXML = this.checkXML.bind(this)
    }
    
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) { 
     if(this.props.xml != nextProps.xml) {
           const newXml = XMLToJSON(nextProps.xml)

            let cData = newXml.smxml.div.__cdata
            cData = cData.replace(/%{/gm,' ').replace(/}%/gm,' ')

            this.receivedXML = cData.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g,' <br>')
            this.ansString = newXml.smxml.div._correctans

            if(this.ansString) {
                this.correctAnswers = this.ansString.split(',')
            }
            this.splitType = newXml.smxml.div._type
            this.checkXML(this.splitType)
            this.forceUpdate();
        }
    }
```

So i don't know what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: When condition will change, one component will `unmount` and another component will `mount`. At that time `componentWillReceiveProps` will not be called. You should try `componentWillMount`/`componwntDidMount`

Comment: yes i did it. but i cannot use  componentwillmount i use componentwillreceiveprops is there anyway to do this without using willMount or DidMount